# Iterating over a list to use in a function

Tags: python, list, function, iteration

I have a function that calculates the volume of a cone.

```
def volume(zmin,zmax):
    #calculate volume using some calculations
```

However for the `zmin, zmax` arguments, I would like to give a list of parameters. **i.e. I want to call the volume function several times using a list of parameters.**

**I actually want to subtract two volume parts of the same cone so that I get the volume in between.**

An example of what I want is:

```
volume(0.0,0.4) - volume(0.0,0.1) 
volume(0.0,0.7) - volume(0.0,0.4)
```

and so on.

How do I achieve this ?

If I store them in lists like:

```
list = [(0.0,0.4),(0.0,0.1),(0.0,0.7),(0.0,0.4),(0.0,1.0),(0.0,0.7)]
```

can I use `zip` somehow to call this list as the function parameter?

Comment: Can you provide something concrete in terms of sample input, and expected output?

Comment: @hjpotter92: I just need to call the volume function as mentioned in the example above. Since I need to call it several times using several different input parameters, I would like to know how I can automise it by just one call